# What's the best way to work with historic dates (as in 10,000 or a million years ago) in PHP?

Tags: php, date, doctrine-orm, wikidata

I'm parsing Wikidata JSON datasets to collect historic data. So far I haven't found the right format to store them in PHP / MySQL (via Doctrine).

For the last few millennia, DateTime seems to work, but I don't want to limit my application to that. It might be totally possible that it will have to process the `start time` property of the [Universe](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q1). Besides, I also want to store the precision of the data, since we might know the rough year of birth of one person and the exact minute for another one.
(Edit: For now, dates are enough, I can live without the time, my example was exaggerated. Still, I sometimes know the exact date, sometimes just the month or even the year.)

I've thought about creating my own class for dates (I'm not planning to calculate time differences or something like that), but I also don't want to re-invent the wheel.

Search results on a certain search engine as well as here are ... underwhelming, sadly.

Any ideas or experience that you can share?

Comment: Interesting question. I suppose this depends on the precision you need. Are you dealing with both current dates and times (e.g. 2000-01-01 00:00:00 UTC) as well as "100 million years before the current day"?

Comment: For precise dates you could use the [calender extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.calendar.php). It goes back to 4713 B.C. Dates before that will inevitably get less precise, and you can use your own approximation system. For instance two integers, one giving the mean number of years in the past and the other the possible range around that.

Answer (score 1):

For a kind of similar use-case, we ended up with storing values for each period of time, allowing to store everything in the db and query at various precision levels.

```
class YourAwesomeDateManager {

    public
        $millenium,
        $century,
        $decade,
        $year,
        $month;
        // and so on...

    function setDate() {
        // Hydrate with the best precision available
    }

    public function getDate ($precision) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

This allows you to retrieve different date formats, and return `0` for unavailable precision fields

The thing is that there is [no common name usage for periods above milleniums](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/78423/decade-century-millennium-what-is-next). So you'll have to be creative.

Comment: Interesting. My draft class contains an integer for the year, giving me enough values for both the beginning of the universe and its ultimate heat death. Month and day then are separate integers. The idea is to map these values to and from a string to store them in the database.

Answer (score 0):

To suggest an answer to my own question: No, there seems to be nothing like this.

So I went on and implemented a function that does what I need. I abandoned my `WikidataDate` class draft since I'd just be instantiating dozens of these just to convert one string into another...

**Thanks for your feedback, feel free to suggest improvements or different solutions!**

```
const CALENDARMODEL        = 'http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q1985727';
const WIKIDATA_DATE_FORMAT = '/^[+]?(-?\d{1,11})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})Z$/';

const PRECISION_YEAR           = 9;
const PRECISION_YEAR_AND_MONTH = 10;
const PRECISION_DATE           = 11;

const PRECISIONS = [
    self::PRECISION_YEAR,
    self::PRECISION_YEAR_AND_MONTH,
    self::PRECISION_DATE,
];

/**
 * Parse a date object (a "value" node) coming from parsing Wikidata JSON.
 *
 * Example string outputs:
 * - "2018-12-31"   the last day of 2018
 * - "333-11"       the month of the battle of Issos
 * - "-53"          the year in which Lutetia (Paris) was first mentioned
 * - "-13798000000" the beginning of the universe
 *
 * @param \stdClass $object
 *
 * @return string
 *
 * @throws \Exception
 */
private function parseWikidataDate(\stdClass $object): string
{
    if (!WikidataEntityDenormalizer::validateObjectProperties($object, ['time', 'precision', 'calendarmodel'])) {
        throw new \Exception('Object missing necessary properties');
    }

    if (!in_array($object->precision, static::PRECISIONS)) {
        throw new \Exception('Unexpected precision: '.$object->precision);
    }

    if (static::CALENDARMODEL !== $object->calendarmodel) {
        throw new \Exception('Unexpected calendar model');
    }

    $result = [];
    preg_match(static::WIKIDATA_DATE_FORMAT, $object->time, $result);

    if (7 !== count($result)) {
        throw new \Exception(sprintf('Could not parse Wikidata date: %s', $object->time));
    }

    $date = $result[1];

    if ('00' !== $result[2]) {
        $date .= '-'.$result[2];
    }

    if ('00' !== $result[3]) {
        $date .= '-'.$result[3];
    }

    return $date;
}
```